# Heroku PostgreSQL connections aren't being terminated for certain Express routes

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku, node-postgres

I have 2 routes that query my Heroku postgres database below:

```
app.post('/signin', (req,res) => {
    let client = new Client({
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: {
          rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
      });
    client.connect()
        .then(()=>client.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '${req.body.user}';`)) 
        .then((results) => {
            if(results.rowCount===1){ 
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.pass, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
                    if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.pass, results.rows[0].password)){
                        res.json('loggedIn') //User and pass are good
                    } else{
                        res.json('wrongPw') //Pass is wrong
                    }
                })
            } else{
                res.json('user not found') //User dne
            }
        })
        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
        .finally(()=>client.end())
})

app.post('/signup', (req,res) => {
    let client = new Client({
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
        ssl: {
          rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
      });
    bcrypt.hash(req.body.pass, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
        // Store hash in password DB.
        client.connect()
            .then(()=> client.query(`INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES ('${req.body.user}', '${hash}')`))
                .then(results => res.json(results))
                .catch(err=>res.json('user already exists'))

        .catch(err=>console.log(err))
        .finally(() => client.end())
    });
});
```

Whenever I use them I notice that their connections to the database lingers. I still see this after performing a signin and signup.
[image]

I waited to see if they would time out but they never did and had to end up using pg:killall, which I'd like to avoid in the future.

Comment: Firstly, I would suggest you use a connection pool instead of opening and closing a new connection every time you make a request to your database. The act of creating a connection is very resource heavy vs using a thread pool and leaving connections open.

secondly you're not handling bcrypt function promise chain when it fails. your .catch() and .finally() call should go after the `});` line as that's what closes your bcrypt function call

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, it was another route being used after signin/signup that wasn't being ended. I ended the other route and there are no connections now